# nicescroll() not working with autogenerated div

Tags: nicescroll

I am using nicescroll library js because i want to make my div scroll nice rather than default scroll.
I want to make scroll to markerlist ul which is generated by javascript.

[image]

I have added nicescroll javascript library like this:

```
<script src="http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/js/jquery.nicescroll.min.js"></script>
```

and function like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#markerlist").niceScroll();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Could you please post the code instead image?

Comment: currently i am working on my local pc but you can check here: https://www.revox.com/en/buy-revox/haendlerkarte.html you will find <ul id="markerlist"> left side of map

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can set a timeout before applying nicescroll. When All contents are loaded then apply nicescroll. Or if you are using a div which shows after clicking a button you can put the code in your click handler function.

```js
$(window).on('load', function() {
  window.setTimeout(function() {
        $("#markerlist").niceScroll();
    }, 200);
});
```